# How to distinguish package, module, class, function in python import

Tags: python, python-import

With a valid python source file, is it possible to tell the nature of `c` in the following import statement?

```
from a.b import c
```

For example, whether `c` is a package, a module, a class, a variable, a function? Would the `ast` module help this task? Would further looking into the usage of `c` help?

Or do we have to execute this statement and look into the properties of `c` to tell?

The motivation of this is to do some analysis on a code base to see what package/modules are heavily used, and how files are related to each other.

Comment: It is impossible to know statically, you must inspect the result of executing the statement

Comment: Hack: If `c.__file__` does not give you an `AttributeError` then it is a module

Comment: If `c` is not a module, then you can use `type(c)` to test

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type(..)` to get some insight about `c` if all you're doing is gathering some data about usage of packages/modules, but I don't recommend using this for any production code.

For example,

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> type(randint)
<class 'method'>
>>> import random
>>> type(random)
<class 'module'>
>>> def a():
...     print()
...
>>> type(a)
<class 'function'>
```